# Why does importing constructors with 'using' cause a different overload to be selected?

Tags: c++, overloading, overload-resolution

It would appear that overload resolution functions slightly differently for imported constructors and explicitly declared constructors but I do not understand why.

Consider the following code:

```
struct BaseBase { int val; };

struct Base : BaseBase
{
    int test;

    Base() : BaseBase{}, test(0) {}
    Base(const Base& other) : BaseBase(other), test(1) {}
    Base(const BaseBase& other) : BaseBase(other), test(2) {}
};

struct Derived : Base
{
#if 1
    Derived(const Base& other) : Base(other) {}
    Derived(const BaseBase& other) : Base(other) {}
#else
    using Base::Base;
#endif
};

int foo()
{
    BaseBase bb{};
    Base b1{bb};
    Derived d1{b1};
    return d1.test;
}
```

Here `foo()` returns 1, proving that the `Base&` copy constructor was called. This is what I would expect because the constructor was passed a `Base` instance.

If I change the `#if 1` to `#if 0`, then instead of defining its own constructors, `Derived` gets the constructors defined in `Base`. I would therefore expect it to have the following constructors:

```
Derived()
Derived(const Base& other)
Derived(const BaseBase& other)
```

which are the same ones defined in-place in `Derived`, plus a default constructor. However now `foo()` returns 2 instead, proving that the `BaseBase&` constructor was called even though the code at the call-site has not changed and is still using a `Base` instance.

The code is also available [here on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEAFZSW9ABk8tTADljAI0zEQAdlIAHVAsLqtHqGJuY%2BfgF0tvZORq7uXkoqanQMBMzEBMHGphZJmKqBaRkE0Y4ubp6K6ZnZoXk1pXblcZUeAJSKqAbEyBwA5AoExAaqANTSzEqTSmPiHtJjdgRjAG5s4gDMi/MAIluyAAwAguInQyPjM5hjIBNTmNdnpwvPY%2B9L9GMEmEMHz28PtcIO1bvdpg95rIPLtSN9fgQIIdQVC9oD3sC0LQhuDMFIAGxjVAEBBuUF3a7A4mk4ideFDCCcFGvGHo3EQLE4ymQySE6lksHcpQQfm0uE/BmSZnQ/YnNHbAHnYajFa7Nx4VaYdCCyFy15yySbPBUMacNlq4garUcuhcnl8kkCikPEWO2lzFmy44fMYWq3oG3YlZCvG8olu8ns0XStEGzbKJRsgz%2BUS4kAgJ4Kk4%2BgD0ObGxwUYyoGTGUzGAEkwP0jGWAO4ZTDihB4It4Iy%2BTJFx3F/SsVB1uzAMac5WqEgKEBsvO%2B9WagPtaf5v3zwN2xNh6NL2eW1ej3FPTcRgGGqzGgGsrOnE7LXuoEEXo7eoEPa5jZzOVGXp8%2Bt/OM0LB%2B8o/h8K5amM6AAdI/7AWyxCYAQPS0BBnAAHQSgQ/x6rs/SdKwID9GY/SkKY/SHMRqAETochyGMCjdL0NxSJsnDEQQBHke0nQANbmIcQgEdwxGkeRpCUf0xGTvx7FkbhpBwLAMCICgqAdng7BkBQNpqRpKDCKInCHEZpBUOpPzEJOEDOBxxHOHYGQAJ4EaxpBoEYRhaAQADytCsE5smkFgRgiMA7A2YFeDwYUmqTgFmAAB4FAYPzOcRyzKOFrB4M4xCOXoWCpaQwztqlnQ0PQTBsBwPD8II%2BliDRMhCNlk6QJ0qDeCk2IEQAtF5khjD1QzoFsuwSDIcicB4knKAUXWaNodSmJwljaGUsTxIIvj%2BF1S1bREXXrRU7grfkhSpI0e2nbN520MUmRHa0J3VCUV0vQ9zQbZUTJdD0fRcHhBFESR4XifFAAc%2BI9fi3AjvVpqHKhiOHGMEC4IQJBzIaK1jHoOluFjLGgtRE0yGxNlcaQvGbJsqE0/TDOM/iAn9EJpBGHxIMBeJkkgNJFPyUpEBIG53jqW45CUKL4vuKsyDeN4AD6qycAAnIrkgeIr8UwyZZluJZ1kBXZtCOYVbkefQPl%2BeFQUhWFAX4FFagxeFCVJSl/Quel%2BEBVlOV5RgAwucVHNe3J5WMCwYU1QImxCCFKCNfI/utSCYmdYEsV9QNQ0EOgSek9IU0zckgQLbo%2Bg5IIViPZtK3bZEQRV6EDcHYEdffYoN1dfdWQt8t3dlxdJSd89QyvQPggTx9MTHQDv2MQvvvAyJFEETrsNGAoctrGrqGa6j6NEMQhM43jYsaYTmzE8n5OyZTpLMFg7jp77bMc2Y/Fr2JBG8/zD8eKc19psYSoM/5FQpoDfokgwHcwgTJTinRNQWXLtwIAA%3D%3D).

My understanding of the overload resolution rules is that all else being equal, the "most specific" (IE furthest down the inheritence hierarchy) overload is selected. This is what happens when `Derived` has its own constructors but not when it imports constructors from `Base`. Why is the behaviour different? Why isn't the `Base` constructor used?

Comment: `Base(const Base& other)` is **copy** constructor.